# SQL Server 2000 Get Ip Address From Connected Client

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2000

I am trying to find out from what machine is coming a connection.

Querying

```
select * from sysprocesses
```

I can see the hostname of the client what gives me `host008`.

However, when I try to ping the `host008` from CMD this host is not found.

Using

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'ping host008'
```

or using PowerShell it gives me nothing, either.

What are my other options?

Comment: 1) Run `netstat -a` on the server and see if there are any IPs listed in the Foreign Address column.  2) Run a network sniffer such as Wireshark on the server to see what remote IPs are communicating with SQL Server--might take a while to filter out the ones you aren't interested in.

Comment: I'd also recommend posting this on the Database Admin site as it seems a better fit for that area of expertise.

Comment: is your SQL Server also a domain controller?

Comment: No, it's not a domain controller.

Comment: hostname is whatever the calling application decided to pass through. it could be anything, from the valid PC name to something made up by the app etc.

Answer (score 0):

There was no host connected. The info's source was a DSN file to link tables in Access.